# How to configure CMake target or command to preprocess C file?

Tags: sql, cmake, c-preprocessor

I originally asked this question on [CMake](http://cmake.org) mailing list: [How to configure target or command to preprocess C file?](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-July/051164.html)

I'm porting build configuration based on [GNU Autotools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) to CMake and I have to deal with C preprocessing to generate a file.

The input for preprocessor is **SQL** file with **C preprocessor** directives used, like `#include "another.sql"`, etc.

Currently, `Makefile` uses the following rule to generate plain `SQL` file as output:

```
myfile.sql: myfile.sql.in.c
    cpp -I../common $< | grep -v '^#' > $@
```

So, the `myfile.sql` is meant to be one of products of the build process, similar to share libraries or executables.

What CMake tools should I use to achieve the same effect?

It's unclear to me if I should use `add_custom_command`, `add_custom_target` or combine both.

Obviously, I'm looking for a portable solution that would work at least with *GNU GCC* and *Visual Studio* toolsets. I presume I will have to define platform-specific custom commands, one for `cpp` preprocessor, one for `cl.exe /P`.

Or, does CMake provide any kind of abstraction for C preprocessor?

I scanned the archives, but I only found preprocessing of fortran files or solutions based on *make* capabilities: `make myfile.i`
So, it's not quite what I'm looking for.

UPDATE: [Added answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11443046/151641) based on [solution received from Petr Kmoch](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-July/051167.html) on CMake mailing list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To take advantage of CMake' `make myfile.i` feature, you can do this:

```
add_library(sql_cpp_target EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL myfile.sql.in.c)
```

Now running `make myfile.sql.in.c.i` will produce preprocessed source for you, using defined `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`. It might be possible to change output name and dir for preprocessed file.

At any rate, you'd need to wrap these `make` invocations into `add_custom_target(ALL ...)` to make CMake run them during build.

Use `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` variable in targets definitions.

If you want to abstract from build tool, you can call cmake itself to build a target for you. Use `${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target targetname` when defining custom target.

---

Alternatively, you can just `add_custom_command()` which runs specified compiler to preprocess files and put them at the appropriate place. But this seems to be less flexible, IMO.

Comment: +1 though your answer is partial, nor really an in-depth explanation, but thanks.

Comment: I wonder why you choosed the alternative way by doing everything manually.

Comment: Because, I can't assume 'make' as final builder will be used. The custom command provides degree of abstraction, to make it portable across concrete builders. (Certainly, the '"${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}" -E' is specific to GCC, but it's just an example.)

Comment: You could've used `cmake --build --target` to abstract from build tool.

Comment: Would be good to update the answer, but for me the comment works too. Accepting. Thx

Answer (score 9):

I'm answering the question to myself by copying essential parts of solution [received from Petr Kmoch](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-July/051167.html) as response to my post in the mailing list.

First, create a custom command using `add_custom_command` (version with the OUTPUT signature) to actually do the preprocessing.

For example:

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT myfile.sql
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}" -E myfile.sql.in -I ../common
  MAIN_DEPENDENCY myfile.sql.in
  COMMENT "Preprocessing myfile.sql.in"
  VERBATIM)
```

Second, configure the command trigger:

- If the command output file (`myfile.sql`) is used in another target, added as a source
  file added to `add_library` or `add_executable`, it is enough to specify it in these commands. CMake will find it as a dependency and run the custom command as required.
- If the command output file is a final output not used as dependency in
  any other targets, then add a custom target to drive the command using `add_custom_target`

For example:

```
add_custom_target(
  ProcessSQL ALL
  DEPENDS myfile.sql
  COMMENT "Preprocessing SQL files"
  VERBATIM)
```

Credits: Petr Kmoch

Comment: Please note that cpp was never meant to preprocess generic files.

Comment: @LtWorf You are correct. I just had to work with existing solution in PostGIS project.

Comment: @mloskot I have a small problem with your solution: the output of the preprocessor is not saved anywhere. I can see the output on the console, but I am not able to save the preprocessor result. Do you have any idea? Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: @sandromark78 try putting a `-o myfile.sql` as an extra argument for the C pre-processor

Comment: @LtWorf cpp might have "never been meant" to do this, but it's common practice for compiler frontends to run the preprocessor on assembly sources. Both gcc and clang do that. MSVC doesn't and requires extra work in cmake to get it to happen.